# why is in my msp430g2553 microcontroller, char 'c' stored as ff63 but not as 0063?

Tags: c, embedded, computer-science, microcontroller, msp430

I'm encountering a discrepancy while converting the ASCII value of the character 'c' to hexadecimal. As per my understanding, the ASCII value of 'c' is 99 in decimal and 01100011 in binary. However, when I convert this binary value to hexadecimal, I expected to get 0063, but instead, I'm getting FF63.

[image]

Comment: You should look at the memory as 8 bit values. The `ff` is not part of the variable. You should expect `63`, not `0063` unless your characters are 16 bit wide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not convert anything only you see the memory dump. You set te dump to be displayed as 16bits numbers (2 bytes at the time). Your char is at the address 0x3fc and it is only one byte long.

Because the system is using [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) encoding the lower byte is displayed on the **right** size of the 16 bit number. See the picture below. Only 2 last hex digits of the address displayed in red (two first do not change)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A `char` on that target is 8-bit.  FF is the value of the adjacent byte (the higher address since this is little-endian).

You are inspecting raw memory, not the variable, and selected a 16-bit view.

In an 8-bit view, you would see `63 FF`.  The watch window clearly shows the variable `c == 99`.